# Python zip shutil

Tags: python, zip, shutil

This is driving me crazy. a simple python script trying to zip contents of a folder 'X'. My problem is the zip file 'Y.zip' contains the sub files and subfolders of 'X' directly under it without the actual 'X' folder. What i expect is when i open  'Y.Zip' , i should see the folder 'X' and under it all the subfiles.  How do i make it ?

```
def zippy():
    folders = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    for each_folder in folders:
        if each_folder.endswith('X'):
            shutil.make_archive('Y', 'zip' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to zip files and folders inside it aswell or just to make a zip that contains both the starting folder and others inside it?
This right here worked for me to zip the first folder and all of it content into 1 zip.

```
import shutil
import os

os.chdir(where the folder is)

shutil.make_archive('folder1', 'zip', 'where the folder is', 'folder1')
```

Comment: basically if you have smt like this folder1->folder2 and folder3 on desktop when you set chdir to desktop and in make_archieve 3rd argument to desktop too it will zip and make a folder1.zip that contains folder1 and in it folder2 and folder3.